# PHP how find if string contains only substring

Tags: php, string, strpos

I am trying to find if string contain ONLY substring 'Student Appt.' in it.

```
$string_could_be = "Student Appt.";
$string_could_be = "Student Appt.. Name Jonathan";

if ($string contains 'Student Appt.' only )
   Return True;
else
   Return False;
```

Comment: Do you mean check if the strings are equal? Give some examples, and specify what you expect each to return (true or false).  I'm just not sure what you mean by stressing the word "ONLY"

Comment: By **ONLY** do you mean equal? Then just use `==`

Comment: Thanks , I was using strpos and it was pulling even if string contains 'student Appt..Name jonathan) .

Comment: Sorry, I did not read question properly, adeneo's (see below) answer is correct i think. mine is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (trim($string) === trim($str_string_1)) {
    // The strings are equal after removing spaces on the ends
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Equal string check:

```
return $string == 'Student Appt.';
```

Containing string check:

```
return strpos($string, 'Student Appt.');
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a simple `===` comparison:

```
$find = "Student Appt.";

$string = "Student Appt.";                  // true
$string = "Student Appt.. Name Jonathan";   // false

if($string === $find)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

You could even remove the `if/else` block completely, and instead just use:

```
return $string === $find;
```